# Getting error:-System.net.mail.SmtpException

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

When running the below code, I get

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException

This code is for sending mail. It works fine with Windows application, but I'm getting a runtime error on Mono for Android. Smeone told me that System.net.mail is part of the System.dll assembly, but I don't know how to use it in my MonoDroid application.

Additional namespace is:  "using System.Net.Mail;"

```
 string username = "abc@xyz.com";
 string password = "1234567890";
 System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new
 System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
 MailMessage MailMessage = new MailMessage();
 MailMessage.To.Add("pqr@xyz.com");
 MailMessage.Subject = "here is the subject";
 MailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("abc@xyz.com");
 MailMessage.Body = "Application run time was ";
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("
 smtp.gmail.com");
 SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

 SmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
 SmtpClient.Credentials = nc;
 SmtpClient.Port = 587;
 SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage);
```

This runs fine on Windows. I'm running Mono for Android 4.2.7, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Can you add the exception details ? Wrap your .Send in a try catch block and post the exception message and inner exception if any.

Answer (score 2):

Try below one **as Test and then change it to your situation If it's working**.Good Luck.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Gtk;
using GtkSharp;
using GLib;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace KentSoft
    {
    class  printTest : Window
    {
    public  printTest() : base("Kent_Calisma")
    {
    try{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("yourmailadress@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("destinationmailadress@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "TEST";
    mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;

    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gmailusername without @gmail.com", "gmailpassword");

    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);

}

catch(Exception e){
    Console.WriteLine("Ouch!"+e.ToString());
  }
}

public static void Main()
    {
   Application.Init();
   new printTest();
   Application.Run();
          }
        }
      }
```

You can get more details from **[Original Post](http://huseyincakir.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/mono-c-sending-mail-through-gmail/)**